# Reference for "tangent of half angle equals cosecant minus cotangent"

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request

The identity $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$ is easily seen  to be equivalent to $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=\csc \theta - \cot \theta$.

So, my question is: **Are there any (online or offline) sources (other than Wikipedia) that mention the latter identity involving cosecant and cotangent?**

The answer may, for example, be a textbook, an online book on Google Books, or a PDF file.

Comment: It would certainly come up in the examples or problem sets for proving trig identities in any number of high school Algebra 2 or Pre-calculus textbooks.  But it probably isn't something they would highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows up in [Schaum's Mathematical Handbook](http://www2.ee.ufpe.br/codec/colecao%20schaum%27s%20(mathematical%20%20-%20formulas%20and%20tables).pdf) as formula 5.43 (on p.16).